# Inequality $\|\nabla u^\varepsilon\|_\infty \le \|\nabla u\|_\infty$ for $u \in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $u \in W^{1, \infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, $\rho \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\rho^\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n} \rho(x/\varepsilon)$. We define
$$u^\varepsilon = \rho^\varepsilon \star u.$$
I am trying to show that $\|\nabla u^\varepsilon \|_\infty \le \|\nabla u\|_\infty$ but I don't really see how to do this. My problem is really to find the explicit form of $\nabla u^\varepsilon$. After that, Young Inequality should help to show the desired inquality (not sure about that, just an intuition).

Clearly, the function $x \mapsto \rho^\varepsilon (x - y) u(y)$ is $C^\infty$ a.e. but I don't see how can I bounded
$$|\partial(\rho^\varepsilon)(x - y) u(y)|$$
by an integrable function (to use the Leibniz integral rule). Does enyone have some hint ?

Comment: one has $\nabla u_\epsilon = \rho^\epsilon \star \nabla u$

Comment: How can I show this equality ?

Comment: It is standard knowledge about the convolution operator, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation for example.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!

Comment: Alternatively, you could use that $\|\nabla u\|_{\infty}$ equals the Lipschitz modulus of $u$.